# Is it possible in C++ to execute function in main thread from function that is running in secondary thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

For example, I have a main thread, there is created a lot of classes and etc. I have a network part, that wait for client data in separate thread. This "waiter" should run some functions from classes that was created in main thread and this functions should be executed in main thread.

How could I do so? If i call needed methods this way `SomeClass::SomeMethod(some_args);` from waiter, sure, they executes in secondary thread.

Would be good have something like this:
`SomeClass::Invoke(function_pointer);` so, the function that function_pointer points on would be executed in main thread? I need an advice for windows OS.

Comment: Can you clarify why it matters which thread runs the functions? The best way depends heavily on what the problem that you're trying to solve is.

Comment: well, some of this functions executes for very long, that lead to network part be unable to process next packets for a while.<br/> if start this functions in third thread, then i getting my app harder and harder to debug because of many threads running and doing weird things with lists, arrays and etc. \n \r (omg just how to make new line here if enter sends this comment)<br/> so i preffer to execute this functions in main thread

Comment: The easier it is to detect bugs in your code, the easier it is to debug. Increasing the concurrency of your code will make bugs more likely to cause crashes, reducing the time it takes to find and fix them.

Comment: maybe you are right at this point. thanks i will think about it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If this is Windows Win32 application, then using the application's Message processing queue is a common approach. 
In the main window of your app you wait for a custom user message, typically it will be something like:

```
(in header file)
#define WM_MYCUSTOMMESSAGE (WM_USER + 1)

(WndProc for you main window)
LRESULT WndProc(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch(msg)
    {
    case WM_MYCUSTOMMESSAGE:
        ... Process something
        break;
    }
}

(On seconday thread)
SendMessage(hWnd, WM_MYCUSOMMESSAGE, wParam, lParam); // Send and wait for the result

PostMessage(hWnd, WM_MYCUSTOMMESSAGE, wParam, lParam); // Send the message and continue this thread.
```

[EDIT]
For a Console application, try using Windows Events. So create a named Event using:

```
(On primary thread)
HANDLE myEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, FALSE, FALSE, "MyEvent");

... later as part of a message processing loop
while(true)
{
    WaitForSingleObject( myEvent, 0 ); // Block until event is triggers in secondary thread

    ... process messages here
    ... I recommend storing "messages" in a synchronized queue
}

(On secondary thread)
SetEvent(myEvent); // Triggers the event on the main thread.
```

Comment: sorry for lame question, but what to do if this is console application?

Comment: akhisp just wants to give a complete answer, kinda bonus. It's not wrong.
I like the send message approach. I applied this method to my inline hooking application that needs to call functions interfering with UI. +1 for you.

Answer (score 2):

Even with the invoke, the function would still execute in the thread it was called in, so that's of no use.

You can have a busy wait or a mutex, inside a loop, in the main thread that is released in the secondary threads, and when released, it calls some method depending on a ternary variable.

```
//thread1
runThread2();
while (true)
{
   mutex.acquire();
   mutex.lock();
   switch(command)
   {
      case command_noop:
         sleep(1000);
         break;
      case command1:
         foo1();
         break;
      case command2:
         foo2();
         break;
      //and so on...
   }
   mutex.release();
}

//thread2:
mutex.lock();
//commands
command = 1;
mutex.release();
mutex.acquire();
//rest of commands
```

Comment: kinda hard to use for me, maybe. but at least it should work. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

In Embarcadero C++ Builder, there are functions [TThread::Queue](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TThread.Queue) and [TThread::Synchronize](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Tokyo/en/System.Classes.TThread.Synchronize), which can be used to execute functions in the main thread. This works from any thread, it doesn't have to be a `TThread`.

```
#include <vcl.h>
#include <functional>

namespace {

class wrapper : public TCppInterfacedObject<TThreadProcedure> {
public:
    wrapper(std::function<void(void)> f) : f_(f) {}

    void __fastcall Invoke() {
        f_();
    }
private:
    std::function<void(void)> f_;
};

const unsigned int main_thread = GetCurrentThreadId();

} // namespace


// Execute the function asynchronously in main thread
void queue_to_main_thread(std::function<void(void)> f)
{
    if (GetCurrentThreadId() == main_thread) {
        f();
    }
    else {
        TThread::Queue(NULL, _di_TThreadProcedure(new wrapper(f)));
    }
}

// Execute the function synchronously in main thread
void synchronize_to_main_thread(std::function<void(void)> f)
{
    if (GetCurrentThreadId() == main_thread) {
        f();
    }
    else {
        TThread::Synchronize(NULL, _di_TThreadProcedure(new wrapper(f)));
    }
}
```